# What is difference between two series?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I was going through concepts of asymptotic time complexities and came across two series:

1. ```
   n + n/2 + n/3 + n/4 + ....... + n/n  //yields O(nlogn)
   ```
2. ```
   n + n/2 + n/4 + ....... + 1  //yields O(n)
   ```

What exactly is the difference b/w the computation of the two series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is about `convergent` and `divergent` series. The one mentioned in number one is in a `divergent harmonic progression` while the 2nd one is a `convergent geometric progression`

The `convergent geometric series` has a sum that is equal to 
`S = n / (1−r)`.  Hence a O(n) time complexity I believe

the `divergent harmonic progression` is simply `SUM(1,n)(1/x) * n`

and we know,

`Integration(1, n)(1/x dx) = ln(n)`,

`Integration(1, n)(1/x dx) = ln(n)` <= `SUM(1,n)(1/x)`

which has a `O(logn)` complexity. And for our case multiplied by `n` and hence has `O(nlogn)`